# Можно ли это слово употреблять в литературном языке?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*дорассказал*

Если нет, то чем его заменить?

Answer (score 2):

У сравнительно поздних литераторов это слово встречается сравнительно часто (поиском по книгам находится со второй половины 70-х годов) , поэтому *допустимо*. Что касается его достоинств, мне оно кажется громоздким и собранным "из запчастей". Без изменения смысла его всегда можно заменить на словарное "**досказал**".

Comment: Не очень хорошо звучит "досказал свою историю". Если начал рассказывать (свою историю), то потом - дорассказал. А если досказал (свою историю), значит, до того - сказывал, или сказал...? Как можно "сказать" свою историю? А другие варианта замены есть?

Answer (score 1):

Да, в словарях этого глагола (*дорассказать*) нет — иначе бы, думаю, и вопрос не возник.
В Нацкорпусе слово фиксируется с двадцатых годов двадцатого века. Его используют в своих произведениях известные авторы — зачем же что-то выискивать или чем-то заменять?

Мне остается немного **дорассказать** о периоде до гимназии... [Андрей Белый. На рубеже двух столетий (1929)]
Она **дорассказала** ему о недавней свадьбе Тани... [В. В. Набоков. Дар (1935-1937)]
Но **дорассказать** о разговорах капитан-лейтенант не успел. [Юрий Герман. Дорогой мой человек (1961)]

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)), на которую довольно часто ссылаются участники сайта, тоже использует это слово: *Кларисса получает письмо от Лектера, в котором он просит **дорассказать** историю о ягнятах.*

Для замены возможны (конечно, в зависимости от контекста) такие глаголы: добавить, договорить, досказать, прибавить, дополнить.